# Does Executor's threadpool count affect sub tasks given main task?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

Assume I have an `executor` which is initialized as this:

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
```

Then i have a main thread which will be executed by above `executor` service `es`. And that main thread calls another sub threads like below:

```
Thread mainThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Thread sub1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                        }
                    });
                    Thread sub2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                        }
                    });
                    Thread sub3 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                        }
                    });
                    Thread sub4 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                        }
                    });

                    sub1.start();
                    sub2.start();
                    sub3.start();
                    sub4.start();
                }
            });
          es.submit(mainThread);
```

Can `subTasks` be hit by a performance wall because of main threads controller executor service *thread  pool* count? Because I specified thread pool as 2 but I am calling 4 sub threads. Even my main thread that `es.submits` is 1 which is smaller than 2?

Comment: Usually, people use thread pool for higer performance. Create new threads and execute sub task seems is contrary to the  original intention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The threadpool only cares about tasks you've submitted into the pool. If those tasks create threads or you create threads in other ways, that pool won't know or care about them.

I hope you don't plan to write code like shown in your question.

Comment: Thanks.. So OS/JVM will utilize cores for subtasks rite? Or we can say, it will continue to do what it normally does for threads.

Comment: Yes, in your example the threadpool is basically irrelevant to the code. You could call `mainThread.start()` and it would be practically the same thing.

Comment: So what is the point of 'newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();' ? It is only there for Future class use?

Comment: It's a convenience method for when you only want a single additional thread to run asyncronous operations.

Answer (score 0):

The threads spawned by your submitted threads are not impacted by the executor's limitation.

Here's a simpler, yet ugly experiment.

```
// notice only 1 thread in pool here
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
Thread mainThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Thread sub1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet().forEach(
                    t -> System.out.println(t.getName())
                );
            }
        });

        sub1.setName("sub1");
        try {
            sub1.start();
            sub1.join();
            System.out.println("mainThread done");
        }
        // swallowing
        catch (InterruptedException ie) {}

    }
});
try {
    es.submit(mainThread);
}
finally {
    es.shutdown();
}
```

**Output** (something like...)

```
Reference Handler
Finalizer
DestroyJavaVM
sub1
pool-1-thread-1
Signal Dispatcher
mainThread done
```

Noticed I changed the max threads in pool to `1`.

What happens here is that your `mainThread` spawns `sub1` and awaits for its completion, then prints `mainThread done`.

`sub1` prints all thread names currently active during its own execution, while `mainThread` is awaiting.

This means you have two custom threads running: `mainThread` and `sub1`.